# Обтекание блока другими блоками

Tags: css, вёрстка, html, адаптивная-верстка

Предположим есть код вот такого плана http://jsfiddle.net/h0czgwgu/

```css
.left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Как заставить блоки `content` обтекать блок `left`, а не пролазить под ним?

Comment: А зачем? Что именно вы пытаетесь сделать? Имейте в виду, что текст в блоке может вести себя по другому.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убрать ширину, добавить `overflow: hidden` и перетащить `margin` для края плавающему:

```css
.left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.content {
  height: 10px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, огромнейшее.
Я почти сутки костыли придумывал... а все оказалось так просто.

Comment: @Kodek, если всё получилось, стоит принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Я принял. Не давало сразу принять по причине таймаута в 5 минут.